# Question about seekg() function of ifstream in C++?

Tags: c++, file

I am testing the following code:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int sum = 0;
    int x;
    ifstream inFile;

    inFile.open("test.txt");
    if (!inFile) {
        cout << "Unable to open file";
        exit(1); // terminate with error
    }

    while (inFile >> x) {
        cout << x << endl;
    }
    cout << "-----------------------------" << endl;
    // Reading from beggining file again
    inFile.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    while (inFile >> x) {
        cout << x << endl;
    }

    inFile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

In the above code, I want to read the file then moving the pointer to the beginning of the file and read again.
I have used `inFile.seekg(0, ios::beg);` to get back to the beginning of the file but it does not work?
Can anyone help me, please?
Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Before you seek to the beginning, you need to clear all error flags, else no operations are done on the stream:

```
inFile.clear();
inFile.seekg(0,std::ios::beg);
```

That's because the `eof` bit will be set, because you reached the end of the file before.

Answer (score 5):

I think you have to reset the error flags of the ifstream by inFile.clear(). Otherwise it still thinks it has reached the end of file.

Answer (score -2):

```
int autoinc()   //auto incriment no//
{
    fstream fp;

    fp.open("birthreg.dat",ios::in);

    fp.seekg(0,ios::beg) ; **//what used this function**

        int t=0;

    while(fp.read((char*)&st,sizeof(birthreg)))

    t=reg_no;

    fp.close();

    return t;

}
```

Comment: neg for no explanation, weird indentation, wouldn't compile due to wrong comment syntax, C-style cast, what is `reg_no`, and I could go on.